# Angular2 dynamically adding/removing form fields

Tags: forms, typescript, angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to dynamically add fields to the choices array when addNewChoice is clicked but still unsuccessful.

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset *ngFor="let choice of choices">
        <div class="form-group">           
            <select class="form-control" id="timeZonePicker">
                <option value="-12" >(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein</option>
                <option value="-11" >(GMT -11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
                    ............
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="startTimeInput">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="time" class="form-control" id="endTimeInput">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
    <button class="pull-left btn btn-success" (click)="addNewItem()">Add Field</button>
    <button class="pull-left btn btn-danger" (click)="removeItem()">Remove Field</button>
```

Here is the component.

```
export class TimeZonesComponent {
constructor(){}

choices = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];

addNewChoice(){
    var newItemNo = this.choices.length + 1;
    this.choices.push({'id': newItemNo});
}

removeChoice(){
    var lastItem = this.choices.length - 1;
    this.choices.splice(lastItem);
}}
```

I've tried a bunch of different Angular.js solutions on here but no luck with Angular2. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why your methods are called `addNewItem` and `removeItem` but in your component you're using `addNewChoice` and `removeChoice`?

Comment: I was looking at a different example and accidentally took the name they used. Changing it to the proper name worked! Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: @yurzui  I have a Question. How to access dynamically added form fields in class (e.g. here in above example TimeZonesComponent class ) ?

Answer (score 0):

No function like addNewItem and removeItem.

```
  <button class="pull-left btn btn-success" (click)="addNewChoice()">Add Field</button>
  <button class="pull-left btn btn-danger" (click)="removeChoice()">Remove Field</button>
```

Comment: How to access dynamically added form fields in class (e.g. here in above example TimeZonesComponent class ) ?